# WCF Json Data Return

Tags: c#, wcf, json

Here what my Problem and requirement is.

// Below is  my List of one Class function i.e is User, i am having 10-15 more class functions

```
  public IEnumerable<Entity.User> User()
   {
        OpenStoredPorcedure("spDB");

        DataSet d = ExecuteDataSet();

        DataTable myDataTable = d.Tables[0];

        var stList = new List<Entity.User>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            Entity.User usr = new Entity.User()
            {

                FirstName = dr["first_name"].ToString() ?? null,
                LastName = dr["last_name"].ToString() ?? null
            };

            stList.Add(usr);
        }

        return stList.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Now in WCF i want one function like below one

```
 public IEnumerable fetchData(int id)
{         
   IEnumerable result1 = null;

    switch (id)

    {
        case 1:
            IEnumerable<Entity.User> result = User().AsEnumerable<Entity.User>().ToArray();
            result1 = result;
            break;
        case 2:
            IEnumerable<Entity.Project> result = User().AsEnumerable<Entity.Project>().ToArray();
            result1 = result;
            break;
    }

    return result1;
}
```

But i am getting this error when using above method

**Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Cannot serialize parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entity+User]' (for operation 'fetchData', contract 'ISyncService') because it is not the exact type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' in the method signature and is not in the known types collection. In order to serialize the parameter, add the type to the known types collection for the operation using**

Now i want that in WCF we call this function and pass on the id its will result json list of that Entity Class.

I am getting Json data when i am using below function

```
public List<Entity.User> fetchData()
{
        return User().ToList();    
}
```

Comment: What does your actual class structure look like.

Comment: public class User :
        {
            public string userId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string EmailId { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public bool status { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 1):

In a case you have a base class and inheritance between the types you return you should add a KnownType attribute on your base class datacontract and then specify all derived types in the attribute

Something like this

```
[KnownType(typeof(YourDerivedType))]
```

Here is some help : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/all-about-knowntypes.aspx

In a case you're returning a types not related to each other, you should do somethig as suggested by OsQu.

Comment: I just edited my Question. Please take a look and let me know if u can help in this. Thanks

Comment: This is correct I am fairly sure. But this attribute on your Entity class and do one for each subclass that derives from Entity.
    [KnownType(typeof(User))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Result))]

Answer (score 0):

I think the probelm is that you need to give type to IEnumerable.

If you know the type in each table, you can create generic method and supply it with correct type.

```
public IEnumerable<T> fetchData<T>(int id)
{         
   IEnumerable<T> result1 = null;

    switch (id)
    {
        case 1:
            IEnumerable<T> result = sync.User() as IEnumerable<T>;
            result1 = result;
            break;
    }

    return result1;
}
```

And then use it:

```
IEnumerable<Entity.User> retVal = fetchData<Entity.User>(1);
```

More info about generics: [Generics C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: by using above i am getting this error System.Collections.Generic.List<Entity.User>' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)

Comment: Oh I missed that AsEnumerable<T>(). What kind of type sync.User() is returning?

Comment: Without seeing your code, what happens if you just change that line to: IEnumerable<T> result = sync.User().ToList() as List<T>; If that doesn't work, can you update your question to give more info about the methods you're using?

Comment: above one also not working. i updated my code above for user list

Comment: I just edited my Question. now i think it will be more understandable. thanks

Comment: I edited my answer. I tested that with my own computer and it worked. (Used ints I assigned in a for loop instead of database query but that shouldn't matter).

Comment: when i call that method from my WCF i am getting this error The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Cannot serialize parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entity+User]' (for operation 'fetchData', contract 'ISyncService') because it is not the exact type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' in the method signature and is not in the known types collection. In order to serialize the parameter, add the type to the known types collection for the operation using ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.'.